# Can someone please tell me if my code has anything wrong with it?

Tags: c, calculator, calculus

I have this project for school where I have to fund a formula and make a program to calculate it. I chose the control formal for bullet ballistics, which is X = (v² / g) * Sin(2 theta) , where X = maximum distance, v = muzzle velocity ,g = gravity (32 as constant) and Sin(2 Theta) = the sin value of twice the firing elevation angle ( if the gun is fired at an angle of 30 degrees, use the sine value of 60 degrees). I am getting weird values in the calculations.

is it possible if someone can identify anything wrong with the code?

Code:

```
//Calculator for bullet ballistics
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define g 32
#define PI 3.1416

void main(void)
{
float X, v, vg, v2, elevation, elevationRad, e, Sin2Theta, Theta2, Theta, ThetaDeg, choice, restart, restart2;
restart = 0;
while (restart <= 1)
{
    printf("Please state what you are trying to find.\n");
    printf("1. Maximum distance\n");
    printf("2. Muzzle velocity\n");
    printf("3. Elevation angle\n");
    scanf("%f", &choice);


    if (choice == 1)   //calculating maximum distance
    {
        printf("You are now calculating Maximum distance.\n");
        printf("Please enter the muzzle velocity (m/s): ");
        scanf("%f", &v);
        printf("Please enter the elevation angle (degree)");
        scanf("%f", &elevation);

        elevationRad = (180 / PI) * elevation;
        Sin2Theta = sin(2 * elevationRad);

        X = (pow(v, 2) / g) * Sin2Theta;

        printf("The maximum distance is %f feet\n", X);
        printf("Would you like to restart? 1. Yes 2. No ");
        scanf("%f", &restart2);
        restart = restart + restart2;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)    //calculating muzzle velocity
    {
        printf("You are now calculating Muzzle velocity.\n");
        printf("Please enter the maximum distance (feet): ");
        scanf("%f", &X);
        printf("Please enter the elevation angle (degree):");
        scanf("%f", &elevation);

        elevationRad = (180 / PI) * elevation;
        Sin2Theta = sin(2 * elevationRad);

        vg = X / Sin2Theta;
        v2 = vg / g;
        v = sqrt(v2);

        printf("The muzzle velocity is %f m/s \n", v);
        printf("Would you like to restart? 1. Yes 2. No ");
        scanf("%f", &restart2);
        restart = restart + restart2;
    }
    else //calculating elevation angle
    {
        printf("You are now calculating Elevation angle.\n");
        printf("Please enter the maximum distance (feet): ");
        scanf("%f", &X);
        printf("Please enter the muzzle velocity (m/s):");
        scanf("%f", &v);

        Sin2Theta = X / (pow(v, 2) / g);
        elevationRad = asin(Sin2Theta);
        elevation = (elevationRad / 2);
        e = (180 / PI)* elevation;

        printf("The elevation angle is %f degrees \n", e);
        printf("Would you like to restart? 1. Yes 2. No ");
        scanf("%f", &restart2);
        restart = restart + restart2;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If the code works as intended, but had the potential for improvement, it belongs in Code Review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review.

Comment: @MartinJames, why not instead support migrating it to Code Review?

Answer (score 4):

I think instead of

```
   elevationRad = (180 / PI) * elevation;
```

it should be

```
   elevationRad = (PI / 180) * elevation;
```

since, `angle(in radians) = PI*angle(in degree)/180`